# Get instantiated contract address from deployer contract

Tags: ink

In the [example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/master/examples/delegator/lib.rs#L78) the returned type is a reference to a contract which implements the `FromAccountId` trait. I would like to just have the contract address (`AccountId`) stored so that the frontend can create instances of the contract. Is there a way to do this? thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The returned reference also implements [`ToAccountId`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_lang/trait.ToAccountId.html). So by calling `to_account_id()` on the returned type you should be able to get the `AccountId`.

Answer (score 2):

After a look into the rust doc, it is possible to use a lower level call to do this.

https://docs.rs/ink_lang/latest/ink_lang/struct.EnvAccess.html#method.instantiate_contract